# Defining powerset of $\Omega = [0, 1]$ in measure theory context

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, terminology

I am confused about the concept of powerset in the following context.

I am reading the Bandit Algorithm book (http://banditalgs.com/) by Csaba Szepesvari. There it gives the following theorem:

Theorem 2.1: Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the powerset of $\Omega$. Then there does not exist a measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ such that $\mathbb{P}([a,b]) = b-a$ for all $0\leq a \leq b \leq 1$.

What does the powerset of $\Omega$ look like since there are infinitely many real numbers in it?

Comment: That's an odd question. The power set is the collection of all subsets.

Comment: It seems you're just asking about the powerset of the unit interval. I understand your concern since each element of the set $S$ is drawn from a continuum, so there are uncountably many elements in it, it's doubly difficult to imagine every possible subset of $S$.  But this powerset contains every single isolated point, every segment, every union of those, and every possible combination of finitely many, countably many, or uncountably many of those.

Comment: It is hard to "visualize".  A version of Cantor's diagonal argument shows that there are an infinity of subsets of $[0,1]$, with this infinity being much larger than the infinite number of real numbers in the set $[0,1]$.